# root pane, parent pane and leaf pane how to load it into root or parent pane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

This question is not same since  I m asking here to load to different parent and it causes error
Here In my case there are root pane , parent pane and child suppose some fxml(name as update) file get loaded into child(stackpane name is stackcountry) if i try to add this child into parent stack(stack name as Stackconsearch) or root stack (stack name as Stackhome)it throw error at

```
     Stackconsearch.getChildren().clear();//this is parent
                Stackconsearch.getChildren().add(root);
```

or

```
       stackhome.getChildren().clear();
                stackhome.getChildren().add(root); //this is root or grandparent
```

in this when user click on any data of tableView new fxml popup now when i m try to add it  on root pane(stackhome which is grand parent/root) it throws error but if try to add it on child stack(stackcountry) then it work properly

```
     tableUser.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
         tableUser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<addcountryController>() {
         public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends addcountryController> c) {
             try {



                    FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
   loader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/updatecountry.fxml").openStream());

                 updatecountryController usercontroller=(updatecountryController)loader.getController();
                    for (addcountryController p : c.getList()) {
                     String ADDID=p.getId();
                     String ADD=p.getName();    
                     String ADD1=p.getDescriptionshort();
                     String ADD2=p.getDescription();
                     String ADD3=p.getCountrychar();
                     usercontroller.setText(ADDID,ADD,ADD1,ADD2,ADD3);
                   }
                    Pane root = loader.getRoot();                       
                    stackhome.getChildren().clear();
                    stackhome.getChildren().add(root);                      

             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

this scenario is like grand parent(stackhome),parent(stackconsearch) and child(stackcountry). fxml load properly when i add it to child but it throw error if im try to add it on parent or grandparent

```
            Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at regionController.countryController$1.onChanged(countryController.java:127)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:75)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.handleSelectedCellsListChangeEvent(TableView.java:3077)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2423)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:1914)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:215)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) 
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What line of code is this: `countryController.java:127`?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson        countryController.java:127 is this        stackhome.getChildren().clear();

Comment: Try surrounding that piece of code with `if(stackhome.getChildren().size() > 0){ line 127 here}.